# prisma - quick model update and save?

Tags: orm, prisma

Just wondering if I'm missing something in prisma.
if i have a working object and choose to modify it, can I just "save" that object like in most ORMs?

otherwise I have to duplicate all the code including all the field changes.

```
// findOrCreate:
const user = await prisma.user.upsert({ ...

user.balance += 1

await user.save() // doesn't work

// so i have to do all this?
await prisma.user.update({ 
  where: { id: user.id }, 
  data: { balance: user.balance } })
```

I assume there's a more concise syntax to do this but wan't able to google it.

Comment: No, you can't do that, `user` will be just a regular JS object. If you want to know how Prisma works and why please read the docs https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/overview/why-prisma#problems-with-sql-orms-and-other-database-tools

Comment: it seems productivity is the top goal but the design choice above doesn't seem to reflect that. but thanks for taking time to share the link